# Player character falls through the floor when respawned

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am following Unreal's tutorial titled Twin Stick Shooter with Blueprint. I am on the step called Respawning the Hero. I've done all of the instructions for that step, but when my player is respawned, they fall through the floor. I am using Unreal Engine 4.26.2 which is a different version than the tutorial uses.

In my game mode, I've tried all available settings of Collision Handling Override within Spawn Actor from Class. In the Class Defaults of my player, I've tried all options for Spawn Collision Handling Method. I've made sure that my PlayerStart is above the floor. None of the solutions I've found by searching have applied to my issue, as far as I can tell.

Thanks!

[Within TwinStick Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vscPz.png)

[Within HeroCharacter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhSpZ.png)

[Within HeroCharacter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez0xQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HeroCharacter spawn location is not set. and thus the location is (0,0,0).

Connect output execution pin from `Set Game Mode` node to the `Set Player Spawn Transform` node.